# Simple question but can't seem to come to logical proof.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$$2\times 3^n+3=3^{n+1}$$
Everyone can see that the answer for $n$ is $n=1$. But how do I logically prove this? For example:
$$3^n=3^3$$ $$n=3$$
Is there anyway this problem can get a factorized answer like my example? It seems easy but I have no ideas.
Lets say this little problem is more complex and I have to prove it in the easiest way possible, I don't just want to calculate in my head for hours until I get the number that fits the equation.

Comment: Note that $3^{n+1}=3\cdot 3^n$ so by subtracting $2\cdot 3^n$ from both sides this gives us $3=3^{n+1}-2\cdot 3^n = (3-2)3^n = 3^n$, i.e. that $3=3^n$.  Can you continue?

Comment: Do you mean $2\cdot 3^n+3^n=3^{n+1}$. How you write it, the equality does not hold.

Comment: @Cornman If it was $2\cdot 3^n+3^n=3^{n+1}$ that would be an identity,however $2\cdot 3^n+3=3^{n+1}$ is a equation which has a solution  namely $n=1$ which the OP mentioned.

Comment: Thanks @JMoravitz! That was the easiest way to solve it and it helped me a bunch :) Can't believe I didn't see that one.

Comment: @kingW3: Excuse me, I missread it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have $$3^{n+1}=3^n(3)=3^n(2+1)=2\cdot 3^n+3^n$$
and $3^n= 3$ only when $n=1$. So $$3^{n+1}=\color{red}{2\cdot 3^n}+\color{blue}{3^n}=\color{red}{2\cdot 3^n}+\color{blue}{3}$$
holds only when $n=1$.

Answer (score 2):

Write $3 =  3^{n+1} -  2\cdot 3^n = 3\cdot 3^{n} -  2\cdot 3^n = 3^n.$

Answer (score 1):

**First way**

$2\cdot3^n+3=3^{n+1}\iff 2\cdot3^n=3^{n+1}-3\iff 2\cdot3^n=3^n\left(3-\dfrac{3}{3^n}\right)\iff2=\left(3-\dfrac{3}{3^n}\right)\iff1=\dfrac{3}{3^n}\iff 3^n=3\iff n=1$

---

**Second way**
$2\cdot3^n+3=3^{n+1}\iff 2+\dfrac{1}{3^{n-1}}=3 \iff \dfrac{1}{3^{n-1}}=1\iff 3^{n-1}=1\iff n-1=0\iff n=1$

Answer (score 1):

Thank you everyone! But the easiest way I solved it is from the help of @JMoravitz [Here!](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2421905/simple-question-but-cant-seem-to-come-to-logical-proof?noredirect=1#comment5002064_2421905)
$$3^{n+1}=3*3^n$$ 
so by subtracting 
$$3^n*2$$ 
from both sides then gives us:
$$3^n*3-3^n*2=3$$
From this we get:
$$(3-2)*3^n=3$$
The Answer is then logical:
$$3^n=3$$ $$n=1$$